# Breaking out of nested function loops in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I am using a nested function to partition and making the filesystem for drives attached to a new Linux box.
I am having a strange issue trying to break out of all loops.

I am keeping track of the nested loop index and using "break n".
When the user replies "n" to the question "Do you have any additional drives to partition?" i expect to break out of all nested loops and continue with the script, but what happens is that the question gets asked again.

Can you help me figure this out?

```
INIT_STARTED=0
chooseDisks()
{
    INIT_STARTED=$((INIT_STARTED+1))    
    # Choosing which drive to work on
    read -p "Please type the name of the disk you want to partition: " DISK

    while true; do
        read -p "Are you sure you want to continue ? y (partition)/n (choose another drive) /x (continue) " ynx
        case $ynx in
            [Yy]* )
                containsElement "$DISK"
                if [ $? == 1 ]; then
                        initializeDisk $DISK 

                        # remove element from found disk to prevent trying to partition it again.
                        delete=($DISK)
                        FOUNDDISKS=( "${FOUNDDISKS[@]/$delete}" )                       
                else
                    echo "${red}$DISK is not a valid choice, please select a valid disk.${reset}"
                    chooseDisks
                fi

                break;;
            [Nn]* ) 
                chooseDisks
                break $((INIT_STARTED));;
            [Xx]* ) 
                return
                break;;
            * ) echo "Please answer y or n. x to continue the script.";;
        esac
    done

    # Any additional disks to partition?
    while true; do
        read -p "Do you have any additional drives to partition ? y/n " yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* )
                #chooseDisks $FOUNDDISKS
                chooseDisks
                break $((INIT_STARTED));;
            [Nn]* )
                return
                break $((INIT_STARTED));;
            * ) echo "Please answer y or n";;
        esac
    done

}
```

I expect this:

```
break $((INIT_STARTED));;
```

to end the nth loop and exiting the function.

Comment: you're just breaking out of the `case`. you should increment `INIT_STARTED` once more before getting in

Comment: What nested loops? You have a recursive function: that's different. (And don't use recursion where a loop will do.)

Comment: Please also show (a simplified version of) how you call your function with nested functions and tell us where you want the code to continue when you use the `break n` statement. Breaking out of loops in calling functions seems to be bad design. Probably there are other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Yes, i am sorry it is indeed a recursive function. I am new to bash. How can i write this with loops?

Answer (score 4):

Don't play with nested logic `break`, just use some variable like `$userStop` and instead of `while true; do` put

```sh
userStop = false
while[!${userStop}]
do
#...
# replace break $((INIT_STARTED));; by
# userStop = true
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting. Wouldn't this be the same thing? I don't need to just break out of the loop but the whole function.

Comment: then just return!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the code to avoid breaking within a loop.
Thanks guys for directing me the right way.

David

Answer (score 0):

> i expect to break out of all nested loops and continue with the script

You can run the function in a subshell and use exit.

```
chooseDisks()
{
    if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "The user entered it all!"
        exit 0
    fi

    echo "The user is still entering... $1"
    ( chooseDisks $(($1 - 1)) )
}

# Imagine the user 5 times enters something
( chooseDisks 5 )
```

But the best would be to refactor your code to just have a big `while true; do` loop in the beginning. There is no need to make this function recursive.